# Android send/receive data from one device to another without third party server

Tags: android, kotlin, location, sms, android-permissions

I am working on an Android app that sends/receives data. I am trying to not utilize a server for data. I want to make this user to user. The users may not be on a local wifi network. They could be physically distant.

I created an app like this years ago. I utilized SMS.

The idea of the app was:

1. User A requests data from User B. Broadcast receiver listening to SMS triggered by approved contact and keyword by user
2. User B receives an acknowledgment of the keyword, creates data and sends back to User A.
3. User A receives data from User B. Again, broadcast receiver listening to SMS triggered by approved contact and keyword by user
4. User A processes data

The premise of the idea was location sharing. No user intervention. App idea was for lost family members, pinging location for lost/injured hikers, etc.

I am jumping back into Android development. This process is now deemed high risk due to exposure of sensitive information from the READ_SMS/SEND_SMS permission.

Is there a way that 2 devices can communicate without the need to access a third party server or API?

If a server does need to be involved, would a service need to be created to register a broadcast receiver constantly running? Battery life? Constantly polling the server if someone wants to know where someone is? What is the best practice to acknowledging a users request to retrieve data from another user?

Example would be, how does Life360 work? Meaning, what architecture/model do apps like this utilize?

Comment: You can use MQTT where an Android device can be used as the "broker". https://mqtt.org

Comment: Tell the distance the devices are separated.